# Send parameters to Cortana Skill

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I created a chatbot which Cortana is using as a skill, it works great, however, I'm currently reading some parameters from a blob storage file and I'd like to make it more dynamic; is there a way to send parameters upon initialization of the skill coming from Cortana? I read here:

[Get the user's profile and contextual information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/get-user-profile-context)

That Cortana can read the UserInfo such as name, email, localization, etc, but I haven't seen any way to enter custom values that I can read once the message is received on init.

I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that Cortana is conversational (RESTful, and for the most part stateless). Ask yourself what configuration is part of the dialog, versus what is part of service.  If there is configuration that is sent from the user, then it makes sense to store it on the session using one of the three contexts described: user data, conversation data, or private conversation data. This is all botframework: [manage state data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

There are a couple ways you can discern if Cortana is configured or not. If you have not stored the properties on userData, assume you are not configured and change your dialog flow.  If you want to check at the time you are invoked, you can always do something like this `if( session.message.entities[0].name === 'Microsoft.Launch' ) { ... }`

In one of my skills, I just do this... `if(! session.userData.bookName ) { session.beginDialog('openBook'); return; }` where `openBook` sets the name.

If this is service related, then you can move your configuration where you like.  Keeping it in Azure storage may still require a service restart to use changes (unless you continuously poll.)  Conversely, you can put the configuration data in system properties (environment variables), either in your `web.config` or on the container.  For example,

```
  <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <!-- update these with your BotId, Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
        <add key="BotId" value="YourBotId" />
        <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="" />
        <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="" /> ...
```

You can set IIS to watch for changed in the config file to auto-restart.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, this bot is actually being used through an HTML and through Cortana as a Skill. I'm passing auth values in order to connect to a custom service to send info back to the user, through DirectLine when accessing the bot through HTML. I was wondering if there is a way that users can setup these values in Cortana, so I can read them once my skill is called. I'm trying to avoid having these values harcoded. My apologies if I have missed any of this in your reply.

Comment: If you set up table storage on your bot, then any userData variables will be visible regardless of channel.  Like mentioned, if you want to configure these variables via Cortana, why not use an adaptive card to generate a form to select the config... or deep link to some webform that stuffs the parameters into shared storage.

Comment: Is there a way (without azure storage) to setup these custom params as user info in Cortana, so I can read it from there? I'd like to avoid asking the user each time to enter the same values. In the end the adaptive card seems like the best option.

Comment: Alternate storage is a new question. It is also not Cortana specific. Mark the old question as answered, and start a new question. I will answer that question when I see it:-)

Comment: Also, adaptive cards are a great way to fill forms. But if you want to prepopulate the form, you still need to save its state somewhere (i.e. userData).  And for Cortana, you still need a spoken way to set that state.

Comment: Well, I'd like to have UserData values to store that information, however and from what I've read, the only ones are "FriendlyName1", "FriendlyName2", "Email", "Location", etc., is there another way to store UserData that can be read from Cortana and sent to the Skill? I will open a new thread if you feel like its needed. Thanks.

Comment: @saman0suke you can store anything you want on userdata if you configure through the bot. The mentioned fields flow through from login credentials via the desktop (or mobile) interface. There is no mechanism to add settings on phone or desktop that would flow through to your bot - unless you build your own channel connected to your own app that would send it.  We're talking end user config right? Because as a developer, you can configure whatever environment variables you want under iis or through the azure portal.

Comment: After reading all your comments, I investigated about Adaptive cards and I ended up creating one that asks the user about init parameters, although I wanted to have something on Cortana's side where the user could save these parameters (one-time only), I understand that is not possible, so this works great so far, I really appreciate your help on this, thanks!!